# Not able to hit a HTTPS Service from application hosted on Webshphere application Server v7.0

Tags: https, websphere, sslhandshakeexception

I am a newbie to WebSphere application server v7.0, While hitting HTTPS Service from my application hosted on WebSphere application server I am getting below error:
 "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure".
 Can someone please suggest a quick fix for this.

Comment: From WAS 7 or "on" WAS 7? The message means the non-WAS side sent an alert to to WAS, so it's best to debug it there.  WAS 7 is 10 years old  and withdrawn from service, it's not a good idea to start using it for the first time in 2018.

Comment: @Covener My application is hosted on WAS and it is in live state. I am just asked to incorporate this https webservice in the application so cant opt for WAS upgrade.

Comment: You have to debug the client then, it's the one who sent the fatal alert.

Comment: You need to add certificate from WebSphere to your service trust store, as currently client cannt establish ssl connection to WebSphere. You didn't wrote where your own service is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to both trust the SSL certificate of the Web Service server that you're calling, and be able to use an https (TLS or SSL) protocol that the server supports.

[WebSphere Application Server 7 is Java 6](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005002), it will be doing older https protocols by default. So if the Web Service's server is using newer TLS 1.2, I think you'll need to [change some WebSphere Java settings](http://developer.ibm.com/answers/answers/206954/view.html).

Also, note that [WebSphere 7 is now out-of-support](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=S913706N13920K48).